# What is wrong with this row insertion?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am working with mySQL in Python with the PyMySQL module handling the connection. dbCursor is the cursor object.

I have the following statement:

```
statement = f"INSERT INTO Machine_status (timestamp, num_of_char, STATUS, emergency_status) VALUES ({timestamp},{num_of_char},{status},{emergency_status})"
dbCursor.execute(statement)
```

However, whenever I try to execute this statement, the program hangs. This is perplexing because this statement similar to it:

```
statement = f"INSERT INTO Speed (timestamp, meters_per_second) VALUES ({timestamp}, {meters})"
dbCursor.execute(statement)
```

does not give any issue. What is wrong with the first statement? I'm truly at a loss as to what it could be. I checked and made sure that the variable names match, I checked the structure in the database to make sure the variables matched what the columns could accept, made sure there were no extra parentheses and that syntax was correct but it continues to hang when trying to execute the statement. The frustrating part is that trying the run the statement directly in the database (using phpMyAdmin) gives no issues. What's going on here?

EDIT1: Added more relevant code.

EDIT2: I've already tried reformatting it to using placeholders instead (i.e. VALUES (%d, %d, %s, %d)). It doesn't resolve the issue.

EDIT3: CREATE TABLE statement

```
"CREATE TABLE Machine_status (id AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, timestamp int, num_of_char int, status varchar(255), emergency_status int)"
```

Complete insert string

```
            payload = item[0].split("{")[1].split("}")[0].split(" ") #returns a list containing everything between brackets of statement
            timestamp = int(payload[0])
            num_of_char = int(payload[1])
            status = payload[2]
            emergency_status = int(payload[3])

            statement = "INSERT INTO Machine_STATUS (timestamp, num_of_char, STATUS, emergency_status) VALUES (%d, %d, %s, %d)"

            try:
                dbCursor.execute(statement, (timestamp, num_of_char, status, emergency_status))
                print("Complete.")
            except:
                print("something went wrong")
```

EDIT4: I figured out what the issue was. pymysql was giving me issues with trying to extract the error code, so I switched to mysql.connector. It finally gave me an error of "table not found". Apparently the table name I was using in the code didn't match exactly what I was using in the database, and therefore it was causing the table to not be found. I changed it, and now the issue is gone.

Comment: Don't use f-strings for SQL queries. This leads to injection vulnerabilities. Check the documentation of your database adapter to see how to give arguments to `execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

As Klaus already wrote don't use stirng insertion use place holders.

Like

```
statement = "INSERT INTO Machine_status (timestamp, num_of_char, STATUS,    emergency_status) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
dbCursor.execute(statement,(timestamp,num_of_char,status,emergency_status))
```

Comment: This is actually one of the first things I've tried. It's nice to know that I'd want to change to this format anyways, but it unfortunately doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: please post your create table and the complete insert string. further the must be an error and trace back which would help too, btw. mysql converts internally everything sp you can use '%s

Comment: I just updated the post with more relevant code, including the create table string and everything relevant to the insert string. Also the most frustrating part of this is that there is no trace or error given by the server. It recognizes that there's an exception, but I have no clue how to extract that exception and display it. I'm currently trying to figure out how to do so with pymysql.

Comment: use mine approach and not %d and i don't know what you are inserting and your traceback please

Comment: I figured out what the problem was, and updated the post.

Comment: it is case sensitive